# Datanitro's remove_sheet throws exception

Tags: datanitro

I'm trying to copy in a sheet from one workbook to another but because i might already have a previous version of this sheet in my workbook I want to check first if it exists and delete it first before copying. However, keep getting an error when executing remove_sheet (the sheet does get removed though). Any ideas? (BTW It's not the only sheet on the file - so not that issue)

```
    def import_sheet(book_from, book_to ,sheet_to_cpy):
            active_wkbk(book_to)
            if sheet_to_cpy in all_sheets(True):
                    remove_sheet(sheet_to_cpy)    
            active_wkbk(book_from)
            copy_sheet(book_to, sheet_to_cpy)


  File "blah.py", line 22, in import_sheet
    remove_sheet(sheet_to_cpy)
  File "27/basic_io.py", line 1348, in remove_sheet
  File "27/basic_io.py", line 1215, in active_sheet
NameError: MyTab is not an existing worksheet
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug on our end - we'll fix it as soon as we can!

In the meantime, here's a workaround:

```
def import_sheet(book_from, book_to, sheet_to_cpy):
    active_wkbk(book_to)
    if sheet_to_cpy in all_sheets(True):
        if sheet_to_cpy == active_sheet():
            ## avoid bug by manually setting last sheet active
            active_sheet(all_sheets()[-1])
        remove_sheet(sheet_to_cpy)    
    active_wkbk(book_from)
    copy_sheet(book_to, sheet_to_cpy)
```

Source: I'm one of the DataNitro developers.